# Get value with Twig for loop from array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, twig

I have an array like this

```
'contents' => array(
              'row' => array(
                    'col-xs-6' => 'grid 1',
                    'col-xs-6' => 'grid 2'
              ),
              'row' => array(
                    'col-xs-6' => 'grid 3',
                    'col-xs-6' => 'grid 4'
              )
        )
```

Now I want to get the key from the array but failed, I have try with this code

```
{% for key, values in contents %}
     <div class="{{ key }}">
          {% for klass, contain in values %}
                 <div class="{{ klass }}">
                      {{ contain }}
                 </div>
          {% endfor %}
     </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Output:

```
<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-6">grid 4</div></div>
```

I don't know why it only appear once, but if I try changing the key name with different value and it works.
Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Did @Thamilan's answer provide you with the answer you needed? Or do you just want to have "row" appear as the 1st class in the 1st div tag, and "col-xs-6" in the 2nd div tag, and then the name within the 2nd div being "grid 1"... If so, there might be an easier answer. Or maybe your contents array is fixed?

Comment: @AlvinBunk Yes, he did but he not give me a solution, so I can't accept it as an answer.  And yes, I want 'row' as the 1st class and 'col-xs-6' as the 2nd class in the 2nd div tag. So, how I can displays it as what the array looks like regardless array name conflict ?

Comment: I was thinking you could use Twig's [length function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/length.html) on the array, but that probably only works for a valid PHP array. Is there a way to pass in the number of grid values as a number variable? If so, there's a better answer. Let me know.

Comment: @AlvinBunk Yes it is. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments:

So let's say you pass in a variable called `gridCount`, then in Twig you can code like so:

```
{% for i in 0..gridCount %}
    <div class="row"><div class="col-xs-6">grid {{ i }}</div></div>
{% endfor %}
```

Let me know if you also plan to change the class values. In the above, I presume you don't need to. But if they are also dynamic, then you need to tell me how they change.

Comment: Good idea, maybe I don't need the class values because i can divided it by 12 and make the result as class. Thank you !

Comment: You are welcome! Please post another question if you need further help.

Answer (score 4):

PHP [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) should have unique keys.

In your case,

1. First `row` gets replaced by second `row`
2. First `col-xs-6` in the second row will be replaced by second `col-xs-6`

So, your resultant array would be:

```
'contents' => array(
      'row' => array(
            'col-xs-6' => 'grid 4'
      )
)
```